# Need help constructing a regex

Tags: regex, string, regex-negation

I need to write a regex which matches strings representing comma separated days of week, like:

```
"Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat"
```

Each day can appear in the string at most once. The order of days is important.

So far I have tried the following patterns:

1) `(Sun,|Mon,|Tue,|Wed,|Thu,|Fri,|Sat,)*(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)`

This one is very bad: allows multiple presence of days, also doesn't watch over the days order.

2) `(Sun)?([,^]Mon)?([,^]Tue)?([,^]Wed)?([,^]Thu)?([,^]Fri)?([,^]Sat)?`

This is the best I got so far. The only problem here is that it matches strings starting with comma, e.g. `,Mon,Tue,Fri`. My question is how to filter out the comma starting string matching this pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed that regex is possibly not the best option.  However, if the only problem with your current version is that it matches strings beginning with a comma, you could just bung a check for a starting comma at the beginning of the regex:

```
(?!,)(Sun)?([,^]Mon)?([,^]Tue)?([,^]Wed)?([,^]Thu)?([,^]Fri)?([,^]Sat)?
```

However, I don't think `[,^]` does what you think it does - in the regex flavours I'm familiar with, `^` inside square brackets matches a literal `^` when it's not the first character in the list - it doesn't match the beginning of the string.  You could replace it with `(^|,)`:

```
(?!,)(Sun)?((^|,)Mon)?((^|,)Tue)?((^|,)Wed)?((^|,)Thu)?((^|,)Fri)?((^|,)Sat)?
```

Comment: Thanks, did't know about ^ in square brackets )

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit complicated, but it fulfills all of your specifications. Maybe regex isn't the best solution for this...

```
^(Sun(,(?=.)|$))?(Mon(,(?=.)|$))?(Tue(,(?=.)|$))?(Wed(,(?=.)|$))?(Thu(,(?=.)|$))?(Fri(,(?=.)|$))?(Sat)?$
```

As a verbose regex:

```
^         # start of string
(         # Try to match...
 Sun      # Sun
 (        # followed by either
  ,       # a comma
  (?=.)   # but only if more text follows
 |        # or
  $       # end of string
 )
)?        # make it optional.
(Mon(,(?=.)|$))?    # same for Mon-Fri
(Tue(,(?=.)|$))?
(Wed(,(?=.)|$))?
(Thu(,(?=.)|$))?
(Fri(,(?=.)|$))?
(Sat)?    # never a comma after Sat
$         # end of string
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is a creative use of [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
^\b(?:Sun)?,?\b(?:Mon)?,?\b(?:Tue)?,?\b(?:Wed)?,?\b(?:Thu)?,?\b(?:Fri)?,?\b(?:Sat)?$
```

Or, if you don't care about capturing each day, you can simplify that a little further:

```
^\b(Sun)?,?\b(Mon)?,?\b(Tue)?,?\b(Wed)?,?\b(Thu)?,?\b(Fri)?,?\b(Sat)?$
```

`\b` only matches between a word character and a non-word character. In this case, between a day and a comma or the edge of the string (start or end).
The word boundaries make sure each comma is surrounded by letters: it will never match a comma near the edge of the string. Similarly, it will never match between two days if the comma isn't there, as in `SunMon`.

Example: http://rubular.com/r/mTCU0ZWtMm

Comment: I've started with `^(?:Sun)?\b,?\b(?:Mon)?\b,?\b(?:Tue)?\b,?\b(?:Wed)?\b,?\b(?:Thu)?\b,?\b(?:Fri)?\b,?\b(?:Sat)?$`, but I think the simplified version should work as well `:P`